What is the percentage of entangled content (matter and radiation) in the universe after big bang? And what are the implications?
I searched for entangled matter in cosmological context but didn't find anything that actually answers my question.
Big bang nucleosynthesis is actually a series of chain reactions that produces a certain percentage of the first light elements. Protons, electrons and photons however, based on the interactions that created them in the first place can have a degree of entanglement. Constant matter-antimatter anhilation as well as other processes in the first moments after BB should also have produced entangled matter in the sense if a particle decays and has a quantum property P, if this property is conserved then the resulting particles summation of this property should remain constant.
Any research that is relevant here? Thank you.

Everything is entangled to some degree. It would be more useful to talk about measures of entanglement than just the binary question.
